# How to indicate that async test case failed

Tags: maven, junit, vert.x

I have this code in a junit test in a maven project:

```
package huru;

import huru.util.Async;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class AsyncTest {


  @Test
  public void test(TestContext tc) {

    io.vertx.ext.unit.Async z = tc.async();

    Async.Parallel(Arrays.asList(

      v -> {
        v.done(null, null);
      }

    ), (e, results) -> {

      if(e != null){
        z.complete();
      }
      else{
        z.complete();
      }

    });
  }

}
```

however, in the io.vertx.ext.unit.Async instance, I only see these methods:

[image]

So instead of calling z.complete(), how can I call z.fail()? Should I just throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call the `fail()` from the `TestContext`:

```
tc.fail()
```

Comment: maybe, but isn't it very weird that `io.vertx.ext.unit.Async` doesn't have a fail method?

Comment: I dont find it weird, you never actually need a fail method there. Async just simply doesn't allow your test to exit until it is not completed. If something goes wrong you probably want your unittest to fail right away and call the context.fail(). If you need some more complex async-call orechstration, you can still use Futures there.